# Logging in and bypassing login screen

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

So I have set up my first website that uses registration and login and it has been implemented using php and mysql. My problem is that if a user has obtained the URL of the pages that he accessed after passing the login page, he is currently able to copy and paste those pages in the URL and bypass the login.

**QUESTION:** Is there any way I can ensure that an actual login has taken place?

My host 000Webhost (free) allows folders to be password protected but I do not know how or if I could tie this into my user database.

This is the first question I have asked on this subject..please be kind.

Comment: Posted this her:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234576/php-setting-the-session-information-in-a-cookie-wont-be-kept-after-page-reload

Comment: @Paul did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are easy ways of checking if a user is logged in and the best way is to use the `$_SESSION` superglobal. When you use the session superglobal, you are basically saving information onto the server about a specific user, and at the same time saving a cookie on the users computer that uniquely identifies him as long as the session is valid (which is usually 30 minutes). In plain English, the php developers made a superglobal that would basically make it super easy for developers to "maintain state" without having to do extreme amounts of code.

This is how you would use the session superglobal. At the top of every page of your website, you would have this portion of code (even above `<!DOCTYPE html>`):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

What this does (among a lot of other things) is saves a cookie on the users computer identifying him uniquely while the session is valid. **NOW...** on the page that the user enters after having logged in, you would have code similar to the following:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];//obtaining username from form
$password = $_POST['password'];//obtaining password from form
// i did not include any encryption code in this example
// so that the example is easier to understand, but keep in mind
// that encrypting your users passwords is super important

//for security reasons, I used prepared statements and binding parameters
//to compare the password and username obtained from the form with
//those in the database (in order to prevent sql injection):
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount()>0)//if a row was found, then you know this user exists
{
//here I am saving information in the session super global that
//can be used to not only identify if a user is logged in on each
//page, but also to see which user is logged in, since often
//you want to give a user his own control panel or other features.
  $_SESSION['authenticated'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($username);
}

?>
```

Now on every page that you have, you would include the following code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['authenticated']))
{
  echo "Hello there ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br>"; 
}
?>
```

The previous code would then echo something like "Hello there John!" if the users name was John. From here, you could include any code you want inside those brackets that you only want users logged in to see **SO USERS THAT are not logged in will hence not be able to view that part of the website, even though they would see the sites logo, and everything else that isn't inside the if conditional**. Also, the previous code does not have to be at the very top, only `<?php session_start(); ?>` needs to be and this is because of reasons regarding how the HTTP protocol works.

Let me know if this helped or if you have any other questions.

Comment: Ok, I tried this too and am getting the following error:                                             Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/a4049291/public_html/frontpage.html on line 14                                     Line 14 is - $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);                                           Is there a class below newbie?

Answer (score 0):

Webeng's answer above has most of what you need, but you need to look into how you made your database connection so that you can use your prepared statements properly. Look up PDO or mysqli database connections.

He's completely right about using SESSION variables to keep track of whether or not a user is logged in, and about using prepared statements for SQL.

The one thing I would change about his answer is the top of each page.  I would use this instead, so that if a user is NOT logged in when the page loads, they are sent back to the login page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header("Location: login.php"); }
```